# I don't know what to do with this ReactJS problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to `React` and facing issues when I want to output "my hello welcome to react". I have gone through documents and youtube videos still can't identify fault.Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo, { ReactComponent } from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
class Layout extends React.component {
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>hello welcome to reactjs</h1>
    );
  }
}
let app = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDom.render(<Layout/>, app)
export default App;
```

Here is the compile error from the compiler

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Line 20:16:  'App' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: you are trying to export a component  that is not defined . In your case it is `App` component which is not defined. you should remove the line `export default App;`

Comment: Since ReactDom is rendering the data it is going to call Layout component, and App component is defined no where so there is nosense of you to export it.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code won't compile properly since App is not defined**.

```
export default App;
```

**You probably wanted to export Layout**.

```
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either remove this line

```
export default App;
```

or 
change the line to this

```
export default Layout;
```

Basically, you are getting this error because you're trying to export `App` component and in the current file there isn't any component exist named `App`

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile properly since `App` is not defined.

```
export default App;
```

You probably wanted to export `Layout`.

```
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export anything. You're rendering the Layout component in the DOM directly.

Please delete this line and try.

```
export default App;
```

Comment: There is no App component defined, and so compile failure occurred

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your class component name to**

```
export default Layout;
```

it will work